# Расширение chrome - проблема в downloads, tabs ,requestBlocking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте,никак не могу реализовать в расширении для chrome.

Отправляется xml http request методом head, потом я в событии `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` отменяю редирект, при этом в событии `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` я отлавливаю http status code. 
И нужно если он равен 302 или 301 (происходит редирект), то он отменяется, и спросить у пользователя (`confirm: "внимание редирект"`) хочет ли он скачать файл, если да - то:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: details.url,
});
```

если нет то ничего не делать.

А если http status code равен 200 то просто начать скачивание, без `confirm`:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: details.url,
});
```

Вот что я пока имею **manifest.json** :

```
{
  "author": "me :D",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/Icon-128.png",
    "default_title": "Мегафон бесплатный траффик",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["http://m.megafonpro.ru/*/proxy/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "description": "test extension",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/Icon-128.png",
    "48": "images/Icon-48.png",
    "16": "images/Icon-16.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Megafon Free Traffic",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "tabs", "activeTab", "", "downloads", "contextMenus"],
  "short_name": "MegaFon",
  "version": "1",
}
```

**content.js** :

```
var clickedEl = null;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.button == 2) {
    clickedEl = event.target;
  }
}, true);
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request == "getHref") {
    sendResponse({
      href: clickedEl.href
    });
  }
});
```

Тут пользователь нажимает правой кнопкой мыши на ссылку и появляется пункт из контекстного меню "скачать", и href отправляется в **background.js** :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab) {
  if (info && info.status && (info.status.toLowerCase() === 'complete')) {
    if (/m.megafonpro.ru/.test(tab.url)) {
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
          if (details.url.indexOf("http://m.megafonpro.ru/") == -1) {
            return {
              cancel: (details.url.indexOf("http://m.megafonpro.ru/mailru/proxy/") == -1 && details.url.indexOf("http://m.megafonpro.ru/twitter/leave") == -1 && details.url.indexOf("http://m.megafonpro.ru/mailru/static/") == -1 && details.url.indexOf("http://m.megafonpro.ru/login") == -1 && details.url.indexOf("chrome-extension://") == -1 && details.url.indexOf("http://web.archive.org/web/20140306220001/http://m.megafonpro.ru/home?from_404=1") == -1)
            }
            if (cancel) {
              return {
                redirectUrl: void 0
              };
            }
          }
        }, {
          urls: ["<all_urls>"]
        }, ["blocking"]);
    }
  }
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    preventDownload = false;
    if (details.method == "HEAD") {
      if (details.statusCode == "302" && details.statusCode == "301") {
        alert('ahah');
        if (confirm("Файл не удаётся загрузить,попробовать скачать по траффику ?")) {
          preventDownload = true;
        }
      }
      if (details.statusCode == "200") {
        preventDownload = true;
      }
      if (preventDownload) {
        chrome.downloads.download({
          url: details.url,
        });
      }
    }
  }, {
    urls: ["http://*/*"]
  }, ["responseHeaders"]);
});



function mycallback(info, tab, getdownload) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, "getHref", function(clickedEl) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("HEAD", clickedEl.href.replace('proxy', 'static'), true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
}
var contexts = ["link"];
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "скачать",
    contexts: [context],
    onclick: mycallback
  });
}
```

далее в background'е отправляется xml http request - head запрос с немного подменённым адресом.

Что конкретно не получается :

1. Скачивание начинается только если http status code == 200 , иначе просто игнорируется, `confirm` тоже не выводится.
2. Событие `onHeadersReceived` срабатывает 4 раза поэтому происходит скачивание 4 раза.
3. Почему-то во всех табах блокируются все request'ы ,т.е зайти на любой сайт кроме m.megafonpro.ru невозможно,пишет что расширение заблокировало этот сайт.
4. И вообще мне кажется это говнокод, много лишнего, можете подправить как будет лучше?